# Pytest =-minimal subset of tests that make failure

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I run pytest on large file with many tests - 2 of them fail. when i run them separately (or even those 2 together), both tests success.
The problem is that i probably do not clean resources well and it happen on other test.
is there an option to run subsets of all tests till finding minimal subset of tests that run together with those 2 failures and makes them fail?

Comment: Good question and a good idea for a `pytest` plugin.